# R - apply function columnwise

Tags: r, sapply

Suppose I have a sorted vector x and a matrix with 2 columns containing 0/1.

```
x <- c(5,7,9,11,15,19,22,25,28,33,36,38,45,47,49,51,53,59)
[1]  5  7  9 11 15 19 22 25 28 33 36 38 45 47 49 51 53 59

m01 <- cbind(c(1,numeric(5),1,numeric(11)), c(numeric(3),1,numeric(5),1,numeric(8)) )

      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    0
 [2,]    0    0
 [3,]    0    0
 [4,]    0    1
 [5,]    0    0
 [6,]    0    0
 [7,]    1    0
 [8,]    0    0
 [9,]    0    0
[10,]    0    1
[11,]    0    0
[12,]    0    0
[13,]    0    0
[14,]    0    0
[15,]    0    0
[16,]    0    0
[17,]    0    0
[18,]    0    0
```

Both columns indicate a particular index position in vector x. Whenver there is a 1, I want to find the index position in x where the difference is 3 for the first time.

So since the first and 7th row in column 1 of `m01` is 1 and `x[1] = 5, x[7] = 22`, I want to obtain a column taking the value 1 at row 3 (since `x[3] - x[1] > 3`) and row 8. I want the same for column 2.

So far I have written a function that allows me to identify these index positions for a particular column, but I don't know how to apply this now for both columns.

```
find_idx <- function(n){
  which(x > x[n] + 3)[1]
}

sapply(which(m01[,1] == 1), FUN = find_idx)
```

Does anyone know how to do it?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You perform the calculation once, for every x value, which is the next entry that is >=3 , there might be a faster way to do this, but since your x vector is small, let's do this:

```
idx = sapply(x,function(i)(which(x-i>=3)[1]))

idx

[1]  3  4  5  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 13 13 15 16 17 18 18 NA
```

Take for example, the first 1 entry would have the 3 entry as the value >=3. Then you just need to call the values out from your other matrix:

```
apply(m01,2,function(i)idx[i>0])

    [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    5
[2,]    8   11
```

Answer (score 1):

As in the other answer (+1), you would use apply with MARGIN=2 (across the columns).

```
find_idx <- function(n){
  which(x >= x[n] + 3)[1]
}
convert=function(x) {
  y=x
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    if (x[i]==1) {
      y[i]=find_idx(i)
    }
  }
  return(y)
}
apply(m01, 2, convert)

      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    3    0
 [2,]    0    0
 [3,]    0    0
 [4,]    0    5
 [5,]    0    0
 [6,]    0    0
 [7,]    8    0
 [8,]    0    0
 [9,]    0    0
[10,]    0   11
[11,]    0    0
[12,]    0    0
[13,]    0    0
[14,]    0    0
[15,]    0    0
[16,]    0    0
[17,]    0    0
[18,]    0    0
```